# Records per page in CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I would like to add a footer to a CListCtrl.

Currently I do it by dynamically resizing the control to add a CStatusBar underneath (with record count, selected count etc) and this works well most of the time.

I would however like to use OnEraseBkgnd to draw a box at the bottom of the control that has this information.

The problem is that if the number of records in the CListCtrl fills the control there is no room to draw this information.

If you add a CHeaderCtrl to a CListCtrl, the control must know to move the first record down to accommodate the header, my question is, is it possible to tell a CListCtrl to list less records per page, thereby creating space at the bottom of the control for a footer to be drawn?

Comment: That's not possible, or at least there is no easy way that I know of. Just do what you were doing before, or put the list control and footnote inside another blank window, don't forget `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag

Comment: I suggest using the HDM_LAYOUT message, you can use this to position the header within the control.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: So with HDM_LAYOUT I can increase the size of the header and place my footer in my header?

Not quite where I wanted it, but it's better than nothing.

The problem I am having with the child status bar, is that it is not working with the new MFC Tab Control.

It works with the old one, but it appears the new MFC tab control gets the size of the ListCtrl and plays around with it internally. If I resize my CListCtrl to make room for the status bar, it appears the MFC List Control notices and makes adjustments to hide my status bar.

Comment: I should add, with all of the other things a CListCtrl can do, I'm surprised that nobody has written native support for a footer, or at least provisioned for someone to create their own internally within the control.

Comment: You could try to increase the non-client area at the bottom by handling [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634.aspx), and render the information in the non-client area (see [WM_NCPAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212.aspx)). For a similar solution see [Insert buttons into an edit control](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/insert-buttons-edit-control).